# missing 'zabbix_server.conf' archive after instalation

Tags: mysql, virtual-machine, centos7, zabbix

I'm installing `zabbix` on centos 7 `server,frontEnd,Agent`, the `dataBase` is `mySQL` and the webserver is `nginx`, I'm following the `instroctions` to install it and I'm facing an annoying issue, after creating the `mySQL` I am trying to configure the database for `zabbix` server. the lest commands I executed were:

```
# mysql -uroot -p
mysql> create database zabbix character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> create user zabbix@localhost identified with mysql_native_password by 'password!';
mysql> grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost;

mysql> quit;
```

`zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql*/create.sql.gz | mysql -uzabbix -p zabbix`

and when it comes to edit this file below it turns out to be in blank, it does not exist.

`nano /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf`

I tried to execute the commands again expecting to see any error massages that I didn't noticed, I was hoping to get a hint on what went wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

In older versions, `create.sql.gz` is inside the `zabbix-server` package. Since your database is on a different host, you need to copy that file from the Zabbix Server to the Database Server.

In latest versions, `create.sql.gz` is inside the `zabbix-sql-scripts` package, so you can install it on the database server.

The latest LTS version of Zabbix, currently 6.0, doesn't support Zabbix Server on Centos 7, see https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=6.0&os_distribution=centos&os_version=7&components=agent&db=&ws=